# Get yesterday's starting date and time and Today's starting date and time in java

Tags: java, date, time

Is there any way to get start and end `LocalDateTime` as (yesterday's date 00:00:00)~(current date 23:59:59) and need to return `LocalDateTime` and not `String` after formatting in java.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"); 
LocalDateTime endDate = LocalDateTime.MAX; 
endDate = LocalDateTime.parse(endDate.format(formatter), formatter);
```

this do not return date and `endDate` is not string so I think not good idea

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is a single date / time, not a period.

Comment: Sure there is... Show us how you tried it first, then someone(s) here may provide working examples. Do you want a period or duration or just the two `LocalDateTime`s *start* and *end*?

Comment: DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
  LocalDateTime endDate = LocalDateTime.MAX;
  endDate = LocalDateTime.parse(endDate.format(formatter), formatter); this do not return date and endDate is not string so I think not good idea

Comment: 0 clear is also possible with startDate.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS).

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking to :

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime startYesterday = now.minusDays(1).with(LocalTime.MIN); // 2020-03-23T00:00
LocalDateTime endToday       = now.with(LocalTime.MAX); // 2020-03-24T23:59:59.999999999
```

Comment: It should be `now.minusDays(1).with(LocalTime.MIN)` and `now.with(LocalTime.MAX)` to meet what OP wrote in the question (swapped MIN and MAX). Plus variable names shuld be swapped as well so `start` is before `last`.